# Upgrade from 3.8.7 to 3.8.8 - Failure - Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php7

My site is down completely. Swapping out my custom template with another very small template allows the system to operate but without most positions. I believe that the error "Using $this when not in object context" proves the problem is PHP related.  I'm looking for the best way to get the site back up on to version 3.8.7 until the template issue can be resolved.  The PHP version on the server has not changed. PHP Version 7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.  Any advice on debugging this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random image module has an issue in Joomla 3.8.8. For details, see:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Module_random_image_PHP_Error_after_3.8.8

The solution can be found here:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/20533/files